# How to update part of a cshtml shared layout on intervals?

Tags: c#, ajax, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, timer

I want to modify the content of a div in my shared layout when there is an update at my database. Whats the best way to go about it ? Timers to check database + somehow update view from controller ? In view c# functions ? ajax ?(don't know much about it) or some other way ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use setTimeout utility of javascript to get timer behavior.

Create a Controller Action and its associated partial view which will have the content you need to load dynamically. You can return a formatted Html from the view or a structured Json object from the controller action whichever is suitable for you..

considering that  your following is your DIV tag.

```
<div id="dynamicContent"></div>
```

use

```
$(function(){
    var function updatecontent()
    {
         $("#dynamicContent").load(URL)

         setTimeout(updatecontent,5000);
    }

    setTimeout(updatecontent,5000);

});
```

to load content dynamically, url would be
YourDomain.com/Controller/Action

```
$.load()
```

will load the content of partial view using Ajax, and you will get a nice behavior on page.

Comment: It might be simpler to use setInterval instead of calling setTimeout from within the function.

Comment: i prefer to use setTimeout usually, but you can decide which timer to use.. happy coding :)

Comment: refer this, so you can choose which one is better to go with...
http://www.worldofwebcraft.com/blog.php?id=169

Comment: Thanks for the info. The ajax part was missing from my thought process. Your approach does seem better here.